# How can we customise the series data object property names "name" & "y" as part of highcharts-angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts

Is there any way to customize the series data object property names as part of Highcharts, actual property names are **name** & **y**.

[image]

And when I am trying to change these property names as **vendor** & **rating** then piechart is not loading in browser

[image]

I would like to update these property names with any code changes as I am getting such data format from REST API service as shown above with different values.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {

  constructor(){
  };

  setStarFlag(id:number){
    console.log(id);
  }

  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Vendor Ratings'
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}:<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          style: {
            //color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
          }
        },
        showInLegend: true
      },
      series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function(e){
              const p = e.point;
              this.setStarFlag(p.name);
            }.bind(this)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name:'Rating',
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Chrome',
          y: 61.41
        },
        {
          name: 'Internet Explorer',
          y: 11.84
        },
        {
          name: 'Firefox',
          y: 10.85
        },
        {
          name: 'Edge',
          y: 4.67
        },
        {
          name: 'Safari',
          y: 4.18
        },
        {
          name: 'Sogou Explorer',
          y: 1.64
        },
        {
          name: 'Opera',
          y: 1.6
        },
        {
          name: 'QQ',
          y: 1.2
        },
        {
          name: 'Other',
          y: 2.61
        }
      ]
    }]
  };
}
```

And see in app.component.ts file `data` object set hard coded data but in my case that object data will come from REST API service in this format

```js
[
  {
    vendor: 'Chrome',
    rating: 61.41
  },
  {
    vendor: 'Internet Explorer',
    rating: 11.84
  },
  {
    vendor: 'Firefox',
    rating: 10.85
  },
  {
    vendor: 'Edge',
    rating: 4.67
  },
  {
    vendor: 'Safari',
    rating: 4.18
  },
  {
    vendor: 'Sogou Explorer',
    rating: 1.64
  },
  {
    vendor: 'Opera',
    rating: 1.6
  },
  {
    vendor: 'QQ',
    rating: 1.2
  },
  {
    vendor: 'Other',
    rating: 2.61
  }
]
```

So, here I just want assign that REST API response to that highcharts data object but in that case piechart not getting displayed. And as I don't have control to update those JSON object property names as that response coming from API service. Now, how I can say to HighCharts use **vendor** & **rating** instead of **name** & **y** to display piechart?

**app.component.html**

```html
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
></highcharts-chart>
```

Comment: You will have to change the data format from "vendor" to "name" before using them in Highcharts. Take a look to the [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data)

Comment: Yeah I gone through but not getting clear-cut idea how we can modify base property names with our own names. if there is any sample code snippet it would really helpful for me @Core972.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Highcharts requires the data format with name and y properties for the pie chart type.

However, it can be done simply mapping data array and invoking init method with mapped one. To make it work you can wrap init method and map data before it (more about extending Highcharts here: ***wrapping prototype function*** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts).

**Wrap code:**

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'init', function(proceed) {

    var tempArr = [],
      tempObj,
      key;

    arguments[2].data.forEach((elem, i) => {
      tempObj = {
        name: elem.vendor,
        y: elem.rating
      };

      for (key in elem) {
        if (elem.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== 'vendor' && key !== 'rating') {
          tempObj[key] = elem[key];
        }
      }

      tempArr[i] = tempObj;
    });

    arguments[2].data = tempArr;
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

  });
})(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8ord92yk/

**API reference:** 
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

**ANGULAR:** 
To make it work in Angular app you can use `highcharts-angular` official wrapper which can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular. There you will also find an instruction on how to add your custom wrapper: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper.

**Demo of Angular app with the wrapper presented above:** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/m4z0628xk9

Another approach is to use `plotOptions.series.keys` and pass an array with only values.

**Code:**

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    keys: ['name', 'y', 'sliced', 'selected'],
    data: [
        ['Firefox', 45.0],
        ['IE', 26.8],
        ['Chrome', 12.8, true, true],
        ['Safari', 8.5],
        ['Opera', 6.2],
        ['Others', 0.7]
    ]
}]
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/07cnxwqp/

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.keys

Comment: Thank you Wojciech Chmiel for your great response. This sample code snippet working perfecrly in javascript application but in my case I need to keep this logic into angular6 component file & while keeping this code getting many errors with self called function(`function`). And I have updated my question please have a look.

Comment: And to do work my code here I can ask to api team to modify property names from `vendor` & `rating` to `name` & `y` then it will wok fine as expected I hope. But in that case we may lose readability of response data at api side.

Comment: I updated my question of how to make it in Angular app. There you will also find a demo of the app. Check it: https://codesandbox.io/s/m4z0628xk9.

Comment: @Venki, that's not the case to force api team to update prop names, you can map response from api call to a format that the highchart library requires: assuming you have `this.data = [{vendor: 'vendor', rating:1.23}]` then you can map this data to chart like `series: [{ name:'series', data: this.data.map(el => ({name: el.vendor, y: el.rating}))]`

Comment: @Wojciech Chmiel, looks I am using different version of angular & your code snippet having angular 5 version. And even highcharts versions are different. So I need to cross verify that. Thank you Wojciech.

Comment: @DanilGudz, I am going apply your suggestion in my codebase. Once done I will get back you. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent @DanilGudz, its working with usual API formatted data without any change in param names after your suggetsed modifications.

Comment: @DanilGudz , can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404116/how-can-we-add-chart-context-menu-in-highcharts-angular ?