# How can we enable all disabled legends of highcharts-angular in single click?

Tags: angular, highcharts

In my highcharts-angular application pie-chart having 10 product legends, the user wants analysis data on product-wise using legends. So, here after disable 6-7 legends out of 10 then user again want full pie-chart with 10 product legends. So, in this case how I can enable all legends with single click? See below:

[Here is my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6h17i).

Step 1: By default all legends are enabled

[image]

Step 2: user disabled 6-7 legends on some analysis purpose like this

[image]

Step 3: Now user expecting enabled all legends with single click rather do enabled one by one.

I been gone through many threads but mostly they relate to different issues.

Comment: This question could do with some code in the body of the post itself. I am voting to put it on hold for now (see [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

Using `@ViewChild` you can get instance of a Highchart component (add a template variable to it to query), then looking at what is inside of this object you can find such object props path: `chart.legend.allItems` which contains an array of legends and each of them has `setVisible` method.

Here is a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2wvhc

```
<highcharts-chart #chart ...

...

  @ViewChild('chart') chart;
  reenable() {
    this.chart.chart.legend.allItems.forEach(item => item.setVisible(true));
  }
```

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks Danil Gudz! Upon reevaluation your suggestion worked out perfectly.

Comment: can you please share your thoughts on this if any [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025450/how-can-we-customise-the-series-data-object-property-names-name-y-as-part/54035320?noredirect=1#comment94974942_54035320](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025450/how-can-we-customise-the-series-data-object-property-names-name-y-as-part/54035320?noredirect=1#comment94974942_54035320)